# Ignoring similar facts in Defrule CLIPS

Tags: clips

I'm trying to create a **family tree** program using CLIPS.

I'm very new to CLIPS and am facing difficulty with some operations in one of the **defrule** I have created.

The operation I'm trying to perform is to create facts for children who are siblings of each other. So for each pair of children, I expect the program to generate **2 new siblings facts**. But the program seems to generate 4 - it's also **listing each child as its own sibling**...

I tried googling for a solution, but I couldn't figure out how to ask the computer to not fire if(?cn == ?sn).

Can someone please help?

```
(deftemplate siblings
    (slot subject-name)
    (slot sibling-name)
)   

(defrule set-siblings
    (child
        (child-name ?cn)
        (parent-name ?p))
    (child
        (child-name ?sn)
        (parent-name ?p))
    =>
    (assert (siblings 
            (subject-name ?cn)
            (sibling-name ?sn))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your second pattern so that the child name matched must be different than the name bound in the first pattern:

```
(defrule set-siblings
    (child
        (child-name ?cn)
        (parent-name ?p))
    (child
        (child-name ?sn&~?cn)
        (parent-name ?p))
    =>
    (assert (siblings 
            (subject-name ?cn)
            (sibling-name ?sn))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's helped! ^_^
But could you please tell me how this logical operation works?

Comment: Pattern constraints are explained in Section 5.4 of the Basic Programming Guide, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! ^_^